# Resizing issue with mat-side-nav and gridster2

Tags: angular-material, angular-gridster2, mat-sidenav

When I toggle the Side-Nav, I wait for the response and then call `gridster.resize()`:

```
 sideNavToggle() {
    this.sideNav.toggle().then(() => {
      this.gridster.resize();
    });
  }
```

Here is a full [stack-blitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gridster-side-nav).

***Make sure to make the application window wide enough, so that gridster shows the desktop layout*** - or better Open the app in a [new window](https://angular-gridster-side-nav.stackblitz.io).

Here is one example:
When I start the app the width of my gridster item tile is ~223 and it is displayed as expected.

When I now **toggle the side-nav**, the **gridster item is resized correctly**:

- when I use the dev-tools I can see that the new width of the tile is 252
- also the console log of the gridster resize callback shows that width of 252
- But the **width in the component is wrong**: it is still 223 (see the text in the tile):

[image]

```
itemComponent.width 252
```

When I toggle the side-nav again to open it, the same happens:

- the tile is correctly back to 223
- but the text in the tile still shows the width of 252
- it seems that the width in my tile always lags behind

[image]

Do you have any idea what I am missing?

Note: in my real application the tile contains a chart component which will auto-size based on it's parent div (which is in the tile). So it is important that that the dom-width/height in the tile is correct when the resize event has occurred.

Notes:

- this also happens with the latest 8.x release of Angular, angular-gridster2 and angular-material: [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gridster-side-nav2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: your question helps a lot to tackle my problem with gridster resizing. thank a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to handle this is to use the [angular-resize-event](https://github.com/vdolek/angular-resize-event) library.
Then we don't even need the gridster [itemResizeCallback event](https://tiberiuzuld.github.io/angular-gridster2/gridEvents)

Here is an updated [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gridster-side-nav2-resizesensor) that uses the resize-sensor

Just attach the resize directive to your container (see file `tile.component.html`): e.g.

```html
<p (resized)="onResized($event)">..</p>
```

and in the callback resize your chart, canvas, etc.  (see file `tile.component.ts`)

```js
onResized(event: ResizedEvent) {
  // resize your chart, canvas
  // maybe use event.newWidth / event.newHeight when required
}
```

Comment: in my case there is dahboard library created using angular girdster. when the side nave button clicked, girdster gird is not straching . how do i resolve that ?

Comment: @ShameeraAnuranga I don't know angular-gridster: This question is for angular-gridster2 - if you are using a different library, you should ask a new question.

Comment: not a different library. I have created a dashboard with anglar-gridster2(8.2.0v).  There is a mat-side-nav . when I clicked the side-nav button dashboard grid should risize, but thats not happen. do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Then it should be the same as the stackblitz example above, right? And in the example, it is working as expected when you click the `Toggle sidenav..` button.